# Since we have borel measurable function, why do we have to introduce lebesgue measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering the reason of the introduction of Lebesgue measurable function after Borel measurable function.

Comment: Because we want to have a complete measure on the real line.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267991/differences-between-the-borel-measure-and-lebesgue-measure